# Create courseWork with studentWorkFolder

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-classroom

Using Google Classroom API, I am simply trying to [create a coursework](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#Assignment) (assignment) where I can assign the [Drive folder](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/DriveFolder) for that coursework then I can upload attachments into that specific folder.

I've tried on the browser with their [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create?apix=true) and also does not work.

Here's my code;

```
    const classroom = google.classroom({version: 'v1', auth});
    classroom.courses.courseWork.create({
        "courseId": assignmentCreationRequest.courseId,
          "resource": {
            "title": assignmentCreationRequest.title,
            "description": assignmentCreationRequest.description,
            "workType": "ASSIGNMENT",
            "state": "PUBLISHED",
            "topicId": assignmentCreationRequest.topicId,
            "assignment":
            {
                "studentWorkFolder": {
                  "id": "1wTM6YYAk1rp4TtsEQwjZnb3qMbR9iPbe"
                }
            }
          }
    })
```

The folder has been created inside the Classroom courses folder as parent.

The only way I found working to create such folder is; when creating a coursework, add materials where the share mode is set to 'STUDENT_COPY', then the API will create a folder themselves. It's a workaround where I can delete all of the contents once the folder is created, but surely there's a classier way?

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

You cannot assign a specific, previously existing Drive folder to a `CourseWork`.

This folder is automatically created by Google when creating the `CourseWork`, if the `workType` is `ASSIGNMENT`.

Also, the `studentWorkFolder` will only be created if there's content to place there, be it a [studentSubmission](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions) or [Material](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/Material) attached to the course work.

#### Reference:

If you check the [CourseWork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork) fields, you will see that, `assignment` (containing `studentWorkFolder`) is read-only:

> **assignment**: Assignment details. This is populated only when workType is ASSIGNMENT.
> **Read-only**.

Therefore, this field will be ignored.

Comment: I've tried without assigning a specific, previously existing Drive folder but that doesn't work. Once the assignment is created, no folder is created automatically for that assignment, unless there are submissions or attachments from students. I can modifyAttachments for newly created assignment since no such folder created.

Is that a way to trigger the folder creation once the assignment is created?

Comment: @smkso The `studentWorkFolder` will only be created if there's content to place there, be it a `studentSubmission` or `Material` attached to the course work. If you think this is not appropriate for your situation, I'd suggest you to file a Feature Request in Issue Tracker.

Comment: @lamblichus I get it now. I've found a way to work for my situation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @lamblichus replied, it is not possible to assign specific folder when creating a `courseWork`.

The `studentWorkFolder` will only be created when;

1. You provide material with `shareMode` set to `STUDENT_COPY`.
2. When student submit attachments to their submission.

For my case where for each submission, I'd like to `modifyAttachments` with custom files, I have created a folder with the name of the `course` then placed all of the attachments in the folder with correct permissions, then using `modifyAttachments` I add the file ID to the submission ID. This still won't create a `studentWorkFolder` but I'm able to `modifyAttachments` for each student.

If I were to add `materials` where the `shareMode` is `STUDENT_COPY`, which this will create `studentWorkFolder` containing the files, then I were to delete all of the contents of the folder; this means I will have a `studentWorkFolder` however on the `courseWork`, the materials attached will still be available/shown. `patch` wouldn't allow to update `materials`.

I hope this helps those also in similar situation.